# merging multiple levels of configuration using typesafe/akka config

Tags: java, scala, configuration, akka, typesafe

I'm looking at:
https://github.com/typesafehub/config

Let's say I want to have a default configuration, e.g. reference.conf, and then I want to have dev/prod overrides (two different application.conf's), and then I also wanted to have host-specific overrides that inherited from both the application.conf and ultimately the default reference.conf.  How would I do this?

e.g., I'm imagining a directory structure something like:

```
resources/reference.conf
resources/prod/application.conf
resources/prod/master.conf
resources/prod/slave.conf
resources/dev/application.conf
resources/dev/master.conf
resources/dev/slave.conf
```

Or maybe it would be resources/dev/master/application.conf?

Somewhere I would specify an environment, i.e. maybe extracted from the hostname the application was started on.

If the application was master.dev.example.com, I'm expecting I should be able to do something like:

```
getConfigurations("dev/master.conf").withDefaultsFrom(
    getConfigurations("dev/application.conf").withDefaultsFrom(
        getConfigurations("resource.conf"))
```

But I'm having a hard time understanding what exactly that would look like using the given library.

I see I could set a config.resource system property, but it looks like that would only allow for one level of overrides, dev-application.conf -> resources.conf, not something like master-node.conf -> dev-application.conf -> resources.conf.

I see a .withFallback method, but that seems to be if I wanted to mix two kinds of configuration in a single file, not to chain resources/files together.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use multiple `withFallback` with the configs that have the highest priority first.   For example:

```
Config finalConfig = 
  ConfigFactory.systemProperties().
    withFallback(masterConfig).
    withFallback(applicationConfig).
    withFallback(referenceConfig)
```

Each of the configs like `masterConfig` would have been loaded with `Config.parseFile`.  You can also use `ConfigFactor.load` as a convenience, but the `parseXXX` methods give you more control over your hierarchy.